# Dynamics CRM update from 2015 Update 1 to CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

I have a Production instance on CRM 2015 Update 1.  Once I update to Dynamics CRM 2016 and get a Sandbox instance after that, will the new Sandbox instance after I update to 2016 be the new 2016 version or the Dynamics CRM 2015 Update 1 version?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that new Sandbox will be CRM 2016 based.

Comment: Thanks Andrii ! 
But can someone confirm? Or is this mentioned somewhere by Microsoft ?

Comment: Yes. I believe that only Microsoftees can confirm.

Comment: I agree with Andrii, it will be 2016. You won't have much use of a 2015 sandbox if your production is 2016 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already have a sandbox 2015 update 1 instance, but your question sounds like you'll get a sandbox after you upgrade.  Our normal upgrade process is to upgrade the sandbox first, perform some system tests, and then send the "All Clear" message to have the production instance updated.  You'll want to follow these steps as well to ensure that an update doesn't break any of your customizations.

Comment: The question isn't about how to upgrade but rather which version of CRM the sandbox will have when they get a sandbox having a production instance of CRM 2016 ;)

Comment: @RickardN After rereading the question, I believe that is how the question reads, but I'm confused as to why they would have a production instance without a sandbox.

Comment: There might be several reasons why you don't have a sandbox instance, one being that you don't have budget for it and you don't have enough users to get it for free.

Comment: Hi... right now I don't have a Sandbox is that we are not gonna start customizing immediately. But we would start doing the same soon... So we're planning to get the Sandbox a little later.

Comment: So, the question is - If I upgrade to 2016 and then get Sandbox, will it be in 2016 as well ?
It sounds pretty obvious that I should get 2016, but wanted to confirm.